# Allocator for [unique] pointers

Tags: memory-management, com

I'm slightly puzzled by the lack of documentation on the issue, so I may be completely off track here:

When I allocate memory in order to return an object through an unique pointer whose value I have modified, what allocater should I use?

The documentation says that I can provide `MIDL_user_allocate()` and `MIDL_user_free()` and the stub will use these -- however that does not make sense in `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER`, as the calling object would need to use (and hence resolve) my allocater.

So, how should I allocate memory here, so that the stub code can properly free the list if the DLL is loaded into *SVCHOST*, and applications can still use the DLL directly if they so desire.

**idl:**

```
HRESULT GetItems([out] DWORD *count, [out, size_is(,count)] ITEM **items);
```

**cpp:**

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE impl::GetBuffer(DWORD *count, ITEM **items)
{
    *count = 0;
    *items = reinterpret_cast<ITEM *>(/* ??? */);
    if(!*items)
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    *count = 5;
    /* fill in items */
    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Out-parameters must be allocated by the one called; they are freed by the caller using the standard COM task memory allocator.

where [*COM task memory allocator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is either the set of `IMalloc` methods or the set of `CoTaskMemAlloc()`/`CoTaskMemRealloc()`/`CoTaskMemFree()` functions that provide the same functionality.

The `midl_user-*()` functions you mention are used for RPC memory management. You need them in case you deal with RPC interfaces, not COM interfaces.